# html5 date input and angularjs: localize input format of angularjs validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

If I create a HTML5 date input like

```
<input type="date" required ng-model="mydate">
```

I get a localized input by supported browsers, like

[image]

in Chrome, where the German date input pattern dd.mm.YYYY is used. If I open the same page in a browser that does *not* support those inputs, like IE or Firefox, it is displayed as a regular text input (and that's totally okay). My problem is the form validation of angularjs, that forces the user to enter the date as *YYYY-mm-dd*.

Is there any way to modify the validation input pattern of Angular.js 1.3 for unsupported browsers to allow the German input pattern? If it is not possible, can the validation of angular.js be completely disabled, so I can validate the input by myself (but still have `input[type="date"]`, so supported browserse show a date picker)?

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu00uzq7/) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: There seems to be much more than a simple html5 input here, but I would suggest you to use the jQuery UI datepicker : it works pretty well and has a thousand of parameters to allow you to manipulate dates very very very easily. If angularJS is expecting YYYY-mm-dd, you can just make a jQuery UI datepicker that shows a datepicker and insert the date in the YYYY-mm-dd format. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ Also, it's a regular <input>, so it won't affect anything at all . Doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ --> dateFormat: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: @briosheje thank you for your hint, but I would really prefer a native solution, as the site need to work on smartphones as well, and I haven't yet found a good responsive date picker, especially for small Android screens, while the native solution works great on iOS and Android..

Comment: jQuery UI datepicker works perfectly on mobile devices aswell. Not sure if it perfectly works with very very very small mobile devices, but in such a case you may want to listen to the user's input and edit it if the format is not the desired one (by using a regular text input instead of a date input)... Perhaps you may want to use a placeholder to give a tip to the user in such a case :P

Comment: @briosheje: Here is a fiddle for !muffel -> http://jsfiddle.net/wgasr49o/